Merge two datasets in a many to one framework, where dataset B's columns are a subset of dataset A's
My dataset A is a panel of individuals, as below. Many individuals can belong to a single family (variable fam_id). I have person variables and family variables in this dataset. As you can see, I have values for family variables for 2012 but not for 2013 and 2014.



person_id
fam_id
year
personvar1
personvar2
familyvar1
familyvar 2




1
50
2012
500
stringA
1000
stringW


2
50
2012
550
stringB
1000
stringW


3
60
2012
710
stringC
150
stringX


4
70
2012
800
stringC
200
stringY


5
70
2012
0
stringJ
200
stringY


1
50
2013
120
stringJ
NA
NA


2
50
2013
370
stringK
NA
NA


3
60
2013
80
stringL
NA
NA


1
50
2014
100
stringM
NA
NA


2
50
2014
500
stringM
NA
NA


3
60
2014
300
stringO
NA
NA



Dataset B is a panel of the families in 2013. It has only family variables, which are the same as the ones in dataset A.



fam_id
year
familyvar1
familyvar2




50
2013
400
stringW


60
2013
700
stringY


70
2013
1000
stringZ



I'd like to 'fill' the NA family variables from 2013 in dataset A with the corresponding values of dataset B.
I've tried
merged_DT <- merge(A, B, by = c("fam_id", "year", "familyvar", "familyvar2") , all.x = TRUE)
But this somehow generates NAs instead of merging approprietely.
I also tried Merging two Dataframes in R by ID, One is the subset of the other approach but I get the error "object '..cols' not found".
How can I do this?

An approach that uses coalesce after a left_join to bring together the familyvars. If you include familyvars in the join-by they're not added if they don't match.
library(dplyr)

left_join(A, B, c("fam_id", "year")) %>% 
  mutate(familyvar1 = coalesce(familyvar1.x, familyvar1.y), 
         familyvar2 = coalesce(familyvar2.x, familyvar2.y)) %>% 
  select(-ends_with(c(".x", ".y")))
   person_id fam_id year personvar1 personvar2 familyvar1 familyvar2
1          1     50 2012        500    stringA       1000    stringW
2          2     50 2012        550    stringB       1000    stringW
3          3     60 2012        710    stringC        150    stringX
4          4     70 2012        800    stringC        200    stringY
5          5     70 2012          0    stringJ        200    stringY
6          1     50 2013        120    stringJ        400    stringW
7          2     50 2013        370    stringK        400    stringW
8          3     60 2013         80    stringL        700    stringY
9          1     50 2014        100    stringM         NA       <NA>
10         2     50 2014        500    stringM         NA       <NA>
11         3     60 2014        300    stringO         NA       <NA>

Data
A <- structure(list(person_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
1L, 2L, 3L), fam_id = c(50L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 70L, 50L, 50L, 60L,
50L, 50L, 60L), year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L,
2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), personvar1 = c(500L, 550L,
710L, 800L, 0L, 120L, 370L, 80L, 100L, 500L, 300L), personvar2 = c("stringA",
"stringB", "stringC", "stringC", "stringJ", "stringJ", "stringK",
"stringL", "stringM", "stringM", "stringO"), familyvar1 = c(1000L,
1000L, 150L, 200L, 200L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), familyvar2 = c("stringW",
"stringW", "stringX", "stringY", "stringY", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

B <- structure(list(fam_id = c(50L, 60L, 70L), year = c(2013L, 2013L,
2013L), familyvar1 = c(400L, 700L, 1000L), familyvar2 = c("stringW",
"stringY", "stringZ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))

EDIT, modified to address coalesceing multiple columns, using lapply to cycle through all familyvars and finally remove the initial x/y contributions from A and B, respectively.
res <- left_join(A, B, c("fam_id", "year"))

num_rng <- 1:2 # set to number of familyvars

data.frame(res, 
  setNames(data.frame(lapply(num_rng, \(x) 
    Reduce(coalesce, 
      res[,grep(paste0("familyvar", x), colnames(res), value=T)]))), 
    paste0("familyvar", num_rng))) %>% 
  select(-matches("familyvar\\d+\\.[xy]"))
   person_id fam_id year personvar1 personvar2 familyvar1 familyvar2
1          1     50 2012        500    stringA       1000    stringW
2          2     50 2012        550    stringB       1000    stringW
3          3     60 2012        710    stringC        150    stringX
4          4     70 2012        800    stringC        200    stringY
5          5     70 2012          0    stringJ        200    stringY
6          1     50 2013        120    stringJ        400    stringW
7          2     50 2013        370    stringK        400    stringW
8          3     60 2013         80    stringL        700    stringY
9          1     50 2014        100    stringM         NA       <NA>
10         2     50 2014        500    stringM         NA       <NA>
11         3     60 2014        300    stringO         NA       <NA>


Thank you very much. Do you know how can I pass the coalesce() to multiple columns? I actually have ~70 family vars in my dataset.

Yes, gonna add an across clause that should work for any number of fam cols.

@llb1706 Added an approach to address multiple familyvars.

It works fine, thank you

The problem is to merge unique familyvars to your data. Currently in your main data frame d1, NA is already a level of e.g. familyvar1 in 2003. To get rid of such duplicates, first merge the existing levels to the new family vars data frame d2, and then merge it to d1 while excluding the old family vars. No need to employ extra packages for this.
> merge(d1[!grepl('^familyvar\\d$', names(d1))], 
+       unique(na.omit(merge(d1[c("fam_id", "year", "familyvar1", "familyvar2")], 
+                            d2, all=TRUE))),
+       all.x=TRUE)
   fam_id year person_id personvar1 personvar2 familyvar1 familyvar2
1      50 2012         1        500    stringA       1000    stringW
2      50 2012         2        550    stringB       1000    stringW
3      50 2013         1        120    stringJ        400    stringW
4      50 2013         2        370    stringK        400    stringW
5      50 2014         1        100    stringM         NA       <NA>
6      50 2014         2        500    stringM         NA       <NA>
7      60 2012         3        710    stringC        150    stringX
8      60 2013         3         80    stringL        700    stringY
9      60 2014         3        300    stringO         NA       <NA>
10     70 2012         4        800    stringC        200    stringY
11     70 2012         5          0    stringJ        200    stringY


Data:
> dput(d1)
structure(list(person_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), fam_id = c(50L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 70L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 
50L, 50L, 60L), year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), personvar1 = c(500L, 550L, 
710L, 800L, 0L, 120L, 370L, 80L, 100L, 500L, 300L), personvar2 = c("stringA", 
"stringB", "stringC", "stringC", "stringJ", "stringJ", "stringK", 
"stringL", "stringM", "stringM", "stringO"), familyvar1 = c(1000L, 
1000L, 150L, 200L, 200L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), familyvar2 = c("stringW", 
"stringW", "stringX", "stringY", "stringY", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
> dput(d2)
structure(list(fam_id = c(50L, 60L, 70L), year = c(2013L, 2013L, 
2013L), familyvar1 = c(400L, 700L, 1000L), familyvar2 = c("stringW", 
"stringY", "stringZ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

